# What does collapsing width height and margin mean for block level elements?

Tags: css, margin

What does it mean that the width of block level elements can not be collapsed but the height can?

And can you please explain this text from the [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins) specification:

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

The meaning of the word *collapse* is causing much of the confusion here.

Comment: Please refer the link where you get these qoutes above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**collapsed margin**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) is the name given to the instance when margins of two different elements occupy the same space.

Consider the following example:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.box2 {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
```

It's difficult to tell, but that whitespace between the two boxes is only `50px`. You might think it **should** be `75px`, because I've specified a `margin-bottom` of `25px` on the top box, and a `margin-top` of `50px` on the bottom box. `25 + 50 = 75`, so why is the whitespace only 50px?

Well, margins can't have any **content** within them; a margin is specifically denoting a **lack** of content. Considering there is no content to display in a margin, the parser thinks they might as well be combined to optimise space.

The word '**collapsed**' comes about because there are technically two different 'segments' of margins existing in the same place at the same time, 'collapsing' in on each other.

Note that this **doesn't** happen with `margin-left` and `margin-right`:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.box2 {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
```

The space above is indeed `75px`. This can be a confusing concept to wrap your head around, but it's important to note that it only affects **vertical** margins. Further information about collapsing margins can be found at **[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/)** and **[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)**.

It's also important to note that, by default, a block-level element takes up **100%** of the **width** of its parent, but **0%** of the **height**.

Here's an example illustrating this:

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
  border: 10px solid purple;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

.child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```

In the above example, I specify both a `width` and a `height` on the parent, though I don't specify either on the child. As you can see, the child element inherits the `200px` width, but does **not** inherit the `50px` height.

Hopefully this helps clarify that a bit!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please elaborate the adjoining margin case.

Comment: Oh wait! I *completely* misinterpreted this at first. My apologies; I'll update my answer now to correct this =]

Comment: I've now dramatically modified my answer to far better cover this =]

Comment: Thanks a ton, it saved my day.